# How do you write a logic function to determine if one 2s complement binary number is less than another?

Tags: logic, circuits, digital-circuits, comparison

Working on logic design in class, and I'm trying to figure out how to write a specific logic function [and by write, I mean something along the lines of (x NOR y) OR (a NOR b), for example]

It asks to assume 2 variables, X and Y, both of which consist of 3 bits (x2,x1,x0, and y2,y1,y0). I need to write a logic function that is true if and only if X < Y, assuming that they are *signed* 2's complement numbers.

I have somewhat of an idea of how to form a logic circuit that accomplishes this by subtracting and checking if the result is negative, which would use full-adders to add X to Y's inverse plus 1. I'm just struggling to figure out how to actually write that down in the form I stated above.

Edit: I really wasn't able to wrap my head around how to write this down as a function, so I went and made an adder/subtractor using a logic gate simulator:
[image: Adder/subtractor for 2s complement]

and I worked up from bit 0, piecing together each logic equation:

Bit 0's sum is:

```
(x0 XOR y0') XOR (Cin0)
```

Bit 0's carry out is:

```
(Sum w/o carry-in) XOR (x0 AND y0')
```

Which is the same as:

```
((x0 XOR y0') AND (Cin0)) OR (x0 AND y0')
```

That then becomes the carry-in (Cin) of bit 1:

```
((x1 XOR y1') AND (((x0 XOR y0') AND (Cin0)) OR (x0 AND y0'))) OR (x1 AND y1'))
```

Then finally, for bit 2 (the sign bit), I dropped the carry out, plugging in bit 1's carry out to bit 2's carry in:

```
(x2 XOR y2') XOR (((x1 XOR y1') AND (((x0 XOR y0') AND (Cin0)) OR (x0 AND y0'))) OR (x1 AND y1'))
```

The first carry-in, Cin0, is 1 for the purpose of converting from a signed 2s complement number. Then the function just checks whether or not the sign bit is on or off, b/c if x - y is negative, then x < y.

I did x = -1 and y = 3 for an example (in 2s complement, those are 111 and 011 respectively)
[image: True if -1 < 3]

I feel like this is all really, really convoluted though, and I can't help but wonder if I've messed up somewhere along the way, or if I'm overthinking this. I just can't visualize how the logic works without... well, visuals.

Answer (score 1):

This page shows you the formula for a one-bit subtractor with borrows in and out. You can use this as a building block for a three-bits subtractor:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/full-subtractor-in-digital-logic/.

$$D=(A\oplus B)\oplus B_{\text{in}}\\B_{\text{out}}=((\lnot A)\land (B_{\text{in}}\lor B))\lor(B\land B_{\text{in}})$$

You can eliminate the intermediate borrow variables if you want.

Comment: Tried to make a 3-bit subtractor, and edited it in to my post. Does it seem right?

Comment: @mrak-p: alternatively, you can compute the whole logical table for the sign bit (only 64 entries) and minimize the expression using a Carnaugh map. This is manageable.

Answer (score 0):

For each bit, you can `XOR` to check if they are different (if they are not, then no need to compare) and if they are different, you can use the value in `Y` (if `(X,Y)` is `(0,1)` we need to return true) and or the results together. If all the `XORs` return 0, the two numbers are equal. Now to implement your specific question, you just need to `OR` the different results together.

Answer (score 0):

If you have just two bit values A and B, then(A > B) = A AND NOT B, and (A >= B) = A OR NOT B.

With two bits A1,A2 and B1,B2 (A > B) = (A1 > B1) OR (A1 >= B1) AND (A2 > B2), (A >= B) = (A1 > B1) OR (A1 >= B1) AND (A2 >= B2).

You can add more bits in the same way. Creating a circuit, you’d check what logic is repeated.